# Is it possible to make a subquery over a group in t-sql?

Tags: t-sql, group-by, subquery

My objective is to write a query that will return all the Categories with 3 flag fields, like this:

ID | En | Ru | Fr

The language flags must be ON or OFF according to if is any Lesson record associated with the category.

My current statement is this:

```
SELECT c.ID,
    (CASE WHEN c.ID IN (SELECT c.ID FROM Lessons AS l WHERE l.Category_Id = c.ID AND l.Language_Id = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS En,
    (CASE WHEN c.ID IN (SELECT c.ID FROM Lessons AS l WHERE l.Category_Id = c.ID AND l.Language_Id = 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ru,
    (CASE WHEN c.ID IN (SELECT c.ID FROM Lessons AS l WHERE l.Category_Id = c.ID AND l.Language_Id = 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fr
FROM LessonCategories AS c
```

The problem is that this query is VERY slow, since the Lessons table has more than 60,000 records, and i'm running over it 3 times.

I'm looking for a way to make this query more efficient.
I had a thought to use grouping on join between Categories and lessons but i dont know exactly how and if it is even possible.

The pseudo-code for more fast query is:

```
SELECT c.[ID], 
    COUNT(l.Language_Id = 1) > 0 AS En
    COUNT(l.Language_Id = 2) > 0 AS Ru
    COUNT(l.Language_Id = 3) > 0 AS Fr
FROM CategoryTreeView AS c
INNER JOIN Lessons AS l ON l.Category_Id = c.ID
GROUP BY c.[ID]
```

It it possible to express this using valid t-sql?
Or is any better way to handle this kind of query?

P.S. If it helps, i don't care to get one bitwise flag field instead of the 3 language fields.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have just to combine your two queries ;)

```
SELECT c.ID, 
       SUM(case when l.Language_Id = 1 then 1 else 0) AS En
       SUM(case when l.Language_Id = 2 then 1 else 0) AS Ru
       SUM(case when l.Language_Id = 3 then 1 else 0) AS Fr
FROM CategoryTreeView AS c
INNER JOIN Lessons AS l ON l.Category_Id = c.ID
GROUP BY c.ID
```

Comment: +1, you could probably omit the `CategoryTreeView` table as none of its fields are used

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
SELECT c.ID,
    (CASE WHEN l.Language_Id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS En,
    (CASE WHEN l.Language_Id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ru,
    (CASE WHEN l.Language_Id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fr
FROM LessonCategories AS c
INNER JOIN Lessons l ON c.ID = l.CategoryId
```

BTW,
Currently you are doing filtering in `SELECT` clause by applying `CASE` statements. You can significantly improve performance of any query by moving filtering statements to the `WHERE` clause which executes before `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with counts in your second example:

```
COUNT(case when l.Language_Id = 1 then 1 else null end) as EnCount
COUNT(case when l.Language_Id = 2 then 1 else null end) as RuCount
```

But in fact, you want to use `exists` in your first example:

```
case when exists(SELECT 0 FROM Lessons AS l WHERE l.Category_Id = c.ID AND l.Language_Id = 1) then 1 else 0 end as En
```

With proper indexing, three `exists`s will be much faster.

Comment: One index seek per row is much, much, MUCH slower than a single table scan.  Let alone three seeks per row!

Comment: @Andomar Let SQL Server decide. If the scan turns out to be cheaper, it will select a scan for performing `exists`. Still, it will be `exists`, that is cheaper than `count`.

Answer (score 0):

A completely different approach try pivot.

```
DECLARE @ctw TABLE(id int, languageid int) 

insert @ctw values(1,1)
insert @ctw values(1,1)
insert @ctw values(1,2)
insert @ctw values(1,3)
insert @ctw values(2,1)
insert @ctw values(2,3)

SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT id, CASE languageid WHEN 1 THEN 'en' WHEN 2 THEN 'ru' WHEN 3 THEN 'fr' END language
FROM @ctw) a
PIVOT
(count(language) 
FOR language
in([en],[ru],[fr]) 
)AS p ORDER BY id
```

Test is here https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/107960/